# Sorting a vector of custom objects by one field

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

If there is a struct:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool pred(string *a, string *b){
    return *a < *b;
}

struct Student {
    int ID;
    int age;
    double gpa;
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
};

int main () {
    vector<Student*>v;
    vector<Student*>v_sortedFirstName;
    //both filled with same information
    // sort v_sortedFirstName by first name
    sort(v_sortedFirstName.begin(), v_sortedFirstName.end(), pred);


}
```

Now lets say the vector `v` is filled with information, and `v_sortedFirstName` is filled with the same information (points to the same spots as `v`). How would I (using the STL sort function, sort `v_sortedFirstName` by **firstname**?

I was thinking this line: `sort(v_sortedFirstName.begin(), v_sortedFirstName.end(), pred);`
should be something along the lines of `sort(v_sortedFirstName->firstname.begin(), v_sortedFirstName->firstname.end(), pred);` but that doesn't work.

Also, if you guys do not mind, I would like to stick with my predicate function above and not use Lambda as I have not learned that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your predicate has to accept `Student *` instead of `string *`:

```
bool pred(Student *a, Student *b){
    return a->firtname < b->firtsname;
}
```

note if you do not intend to modify data change parameters type to `const Student *` and that would make your code cleaner and safer (if you put code in `pred`, that by mistake tries to modify that structure then compiler will reject to compile and it would be easy to detect and fix that mistake):

```
bool pred(const Student *a, const Student *b){
    return a->firtname < b->firtsname;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So for `const`, that means if anyone tries to modify values in the function (like `a->firstname = "John";`) it wouldn't let it happen?

Comment: @StacksAndParsing yes exactly that